# scrollTop not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problem with scrolltop in firefox and IE
I used scrolltop more than 2 time in my code in part one it works but in part two it doesnt 
I have two arrows "next" and "prev" which when clicking on them page scroll to specific part,
I cant find how can I fix it?

**jquery :**

```
var lchiled=$("ul#portfolio li").last();
var fchiled=$("ul#portfolio li").first();
$('li.section').first();
$("ul#portfolio li:first-child").addClass("current");

$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var t = $(this).attr('name');

    that = $(this);


    if (t === 'next') {
        if($('.current').next('.section').length==0)
            var $next = $('li.section').first();
        else
            var $next = $('.current').next('.section');

        var top = $next.offset().top -65;
        $('.current').removeClass('current');

        $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: top,
        }, 

        function () {
        $next.addClass('current');
        // alert(top);
        });
    }
    else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('li.section').length > 0) {
        var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
        var top = $prev.offset().top -65;
        $('.current').removeClass('current');

        $('body').animate({
             scrollTop: top,     
        }, function () {
            $prev.addClass('current');
        });
    } 

});
```

**html :**

```
<div id="container">

   <ul id="portfolio" class="clearfix">

   </ul>

</div>
```

lis are dynamically produce  with jquery codes

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see this (with css)?

Comment: @mayrop No it's local

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be like this

```
$('body,html').animate({
         scrollTop: top,     
    }, function () {
        $prev.addClass('current');
    });
```

insted of

```
$('body').animate({
         scrollTop: top,     
    }, function () {
        $prev.addClass('current');
    });
```

I forget to update the prev part so this problem happened.

Answer (score 1):

You use `.animate` on `scrollTop` in two places. In one, you (correctly) use `html,body` as the selector. In the other, you only use `body`. And you wonder why it doesn't work in some browsers ;)

Answer (score -1):

try `var offset = $(window).scrollTop();` this .

Comment: it dosent answer but I find the problem !

Comment: @Ashwani, This is more of a comment than actual answer. Please use comment option, if you don't have enough reputation please wait till you get it..

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.scrollTo(x,y)`